# UIKit glitch on iOS14 for projects without UISceneDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios14

I see serious glitch in iOS 14 with old XCode projects not having UISceneDelegate. It is fairly easy to reproduce. Just have a subview called topView with white background in initial view controller and set it to hidden in iOS 14. This is the only code needed to reproduce the issue:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var topPanel: UIView!
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.topPanel.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

The app must be launched in landscape mode to see this glitch. The unhidden view unveils like a curtain from left to right. The problem will be more clear in video than a gif but since we can't attach video in SO, let's work with a gif. This is not the case with projects with UISceneDelegate.

So now I don't expect Apple to fix it anytime soon, what is the reasonable workaround for me if I have to target iOS 12 or lower?

[image: s14]

Also attaching component images of gif to be more clear.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this reproducible on device too?

Comment: Yes, its only from device!